# A query with LIKE clause using wildcards around the search string returns all rows

Tags: php, mysql

When I try to bind `$string`, it either returns no results or all of the results I have in my table.

If I use `$string= '%' . $string . '%'` or `$string= "%" . $string . "%"`
it returns all of the rows.

and when I try to bind `$string` directly without any modification, it returns no result at all.

I tried using different formatting techniques like trim and string replace functions but so far nothing worked for me. I'm using PHP/5.6.20.

```php
    function searchPatient($string){
            $string= '%' . $string . '%';
            $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT id, fname, lname, mname, sex, title, DOB FROM patient_data WHERE fname LIKE ?");
            $stmt->bind_param("s",$string);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->bind_result($id, $fname, $lname, $mname, $sex, $title, $DOB);

            $pat_record = array(); 

            while($stmt->fetch()){
                $patient  = array();
                $patient['id'] = $id; 
                $patient['fname'] = $fname; 
                $patient['lname'] = $lname;
                $patient['mname'] = $mname;
                $patient['sex'] = $sex;
                $patient['title'] = $title;
                $patient['DOB'] = $DOB;         
                array_push($pat_record, $patient); 
            }
            return $pat_record; 
        }
```

When i replace `?` with actual search terms like `'John'` or `'%John%'` it works as it should. does anyone have a clue on whats going on here?

Comment: Your $string is empty

Comment: `var_dump($string)` Also I'd just return a `fetch_all` in associative format, that'll be the same as your `while` and assignments.

Comment: $string is not empty, tbh that what i thought first but then I tried echo $string and it is indeed not empty.

Comment: What do you get if you `var_dump($string);` either before or after your bind_param?

Comment: var_dump returns beforestring(5) "%cat%"  afterstring(5) "%cat%"  beforestring(2) "%%"  afterstring(2) "%%" where the $string="cat"

Comment: Interesting that you pass a string, then an empty string. What happens between those two sets of dumps/searches?

Comment: Good catch, I passed it only once,  but for some reason It returns a dump value of 5 and an empty one of 2.

Comment: Go through your execution you must have `searchPatient()` twice... or a script is included twice that has that call

Comment: Hmm the second value is actually a NULL, I am trying to find out why. thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a query with LIKE clause using wildcards around the search string returns all rows, it means that the search string **is empty**. Despite any notions you may have about its contents. This is a solid fact and the actual answer to this question.

Comment: Yeah I can see why it is appearing as empty. var_dump is returning the string value and a null value for this particular search function.